# How to source only select workspaces?

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There are multiple catkin workspaces on my station (from different users).

If I source the setup.bash of only my workspace in my .bashrc it still sources a couple of other workspaces. Or that's what I think since I can roscd into those packages as well as see it in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

What is the reason for this?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195877/how-to-source-only-select-workspaces-?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-10-24**:
If you reset ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and re-source ~/.bashrc, what do you get ? :

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=
source ~/.bashrc
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

At least you will know exactly what comes from your .bashrc

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-10-24**:
I did. I sourced /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash. That makes ROS_PACKAGE_PATH have just the hydro default directories. And then I sourced the setup.bash from one of my workspaces devel space. And couple other workspaces are added along with that.

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-10-24**:
How about deleting your build/ and devel/ from that workspace and rebuilding the whole workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The behaviour your are observing has to do with how catkin workspaces are chained.

At the time you created your catkin workspace, other workspaces had already been created and sourced within the shell you were using.

A quick fix (if you only want to have the system-wide installed ROS packages and your catkin workspace sourced) is:

```
cd your_catkin_ws/
rm -rf build/ devel/
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
catkin_make
```

Then, remember to have only one line in your `.bashrc`:

```
source path_to_your_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

See the answers (particularly the second one) to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/190536/catkin-fails-to-chain-workspaces/#190588) for a more detailed explanation on how chaining of catkin workspaces actually works.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-27**:
`build` and `devel` are usually not under src. I think it should also be sufficient to only delete build/devel, source the hydro/setup.bash and catkin_make.

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-10-27**:
You are right, there is no need to delete the `CmakeLists.txt`. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm editing my answer to remove those commands.